# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am getting the following exception from the users on google play:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

Its been 8 months that I have uploaded my app on market and this is the first time I have got this exception. Can anyone tell me, how this exception came all of a sudden and what this is about. I searched the net but couldn't find anything. Please help.

Comment: is it on a specific API level?

Comment: don't know just got the exception on dev console.

Answer (score 3):

Since there were no intent filters specified in the manifest for this
Service the default for android:exported was false.  When you set
android:exported="true" the other application will be able to start the
Service.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported

Comment: What makes you think there were no intent-filters in his service?

Comment: also, that's not his service, that's google gcm registration service.